# Interpreting SOFR OIS Curve from CME

Tags: yield-curve, ois, sofr, cme

I have a doubt regarding the daily SOFR OIS Curve published by CME.

https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/cleared-otc-sofr-swaps.html#sofroiscurve

If we refer to the curve dated 22 Jul 2022... [image: SOFR OIS on 22 Jul 2022]

The one year OIS rate is displayed at 0.3074%, this means that the OIS SWAP Rate for next 12 months is 0.3074%, right ? However, the latest SOFR Rate is ~ 1.50% - 1.53%. I was expecting the SWAP rate to be higher.

Would appreciate your opinions.

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: I've asked a few people and no one knew what the CME outright rate is showing. Could be a bug.

Comment: Thanks @oronimbus, the number looks way off.